# dynamodb: Import data from csv, ignore importing existing records. import only new records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I keep getting `json` file, which contains a list of items.

And I want to import this list into `dynamodb`.

After the first import, another `json` file i want to import. This json file may contain some items from previous `json` file

So while importing I want to avoid them being inserted into `dynamodb`.

Also, I want to create a stream for the newly inserted items

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Just import using a [`ConditionExpression`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html) and use the [`attribute_not_exists`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.PreventingOverwrites) function.

```
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name my-table \
    --item file://item.json \
    --condition-expression "attribute_not_exists(pk)"
```